# New VSCode Settings editor: onDidChangeConfiguration invoked at every keystroke

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my extension plugin I've registered a `onDidChangeConfiguration` event listener:

```
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  vscode.workspace.onDidChangeConfiguration(event => {
    ...
}
```

In vscode 1.27 with the new [Settings editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_27#_settings-editor) the
callback `onDidChangeConfiguration` is invoked at each keystroke when changing the property value, and this changed the old behavoir:

In previous vscode versions (and in the settings editor opened with command `Open setting (JSON)`) the change configuration event is triggered when I save my new settings.

Is there a way to trigger a `onDidChangeConfiguration` at least at the end of property editing? (return keystroke or focus getting off)

### Update: a specific use case

One of my properties represents a makefile build directory and when I change the value `onDidChangeConfiguration` cd to that directory and launches make commands to configure cpp intellisense.

This new behavior introduces nasty side effects and a bad user experience: the below image get an idea:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well-timed question because I just merged a PR that addresses this in VS Code. The debounce rate for text input settings has been changed to 1s, so the change should be triggered much less often.

You can see the change in the next Insiders build next week, or in 1.28 in a couple weeks.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/58537

Comment: Thanks @Rob, the debouncing attenuates the problem, but in my case does not resolve the problem, see the question update to get an idea.

Comment: Could you comment on https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/58537 and help me decide how to move forward? An even longer debounce, a different mode with a "save button" for individual settings to opt into, any other ideas are welcome...